# Wrong action of Open command in Fortran( Insted read open command opens .txt file )

Tags: fortran, gfortran, tdm-gcc

This is my simple code:

```
Program Example_Code

Implicit none

Integer :: iERR

  Open( Unit = 15, File = 'Read_Something.txt', Action = 'Read', Status = 'Unknown', iostat = iERR )

    If ( iERR /= 0 ) stop ( "There is no file Read_Something.txt !!!")


  Close( 15, Status = 'Keep')

End Program Example_Code
```

In the project directory I did not create any .txt file( because I want to test opening file with iostat) and afther the program ends I find `Read_Something.txt`in the project folder.

What is wrong in this example?
Why does this obvious error occur?

IDE: Code::Blocks 17.12, TDM_GCC_5.0.1 - 03

OS: Win 10 X64

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `status="unknown"`, that means the compiler can create the file for you so that you can read from it. If you want to open a file only when it exist, use `status="old"`.

BTW, I find it quite useless to explicitly specify any `="unknown"`, just leave the argument out completely. But that is my personal style.

Comment: @francescalus, The Fortran standard states for `ACTION=`   __For a new file, the processor creates the file with a set of allowed actions that includes the specified action.__